# What is an idiomatic French equivalent of the English expression “hold a gun to your head”?

Tags: anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, allemand

> {I said}: **Sans vouloir te mettre la pression**, je dois savoir. Admettons qu’il cherche à me faire concurrence. Dans quel camp seras-tu ?

In German, you can express the same idea in a similar way, "ich will dir nicht die Pistole auf die Brust setzen, aber ...", with a slight difference of "holding a gun to your *chest*".

I wonder if French has an equivalent expression? In spontaneous speech, I couldn’t come up with any metaphorical expression more likely to conjure up visual imagery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Pointer un pistolet sur la tempe / mettre un couteau sur la gorge**

En français le pistolet est pointé sur la tempe.

> Libre-échange: Theresa May pointe un pistolet sur la tempe des Européens. (Source : [lexpansion.lexpress](http://lexpansion.lexpress.fr))
>
> Un "pistolet sur la tempe" de Tsipras : l'autre vision de la crise grecque. (Source : [L'Obs](http://tempsreel.nouvelobs.com/monde/20150713.AFP3643/un-pistolet-sur-la-tempe-de-tsipras-l-autre-vision-de-la-crise-grecque.html))

Mais le français est versatile en la matière et parfois c'est le couteau sur/sous la gorge :

> Charles Michel: «On ne peut pas mettre le couteau sous la gorge de Cameron» (Source : [Le Soir](http://www.lesoir.be/1251920/article/actualite/belgique/politique/2016-06-28/charles-michel-on-ne-peut-pas-mettre-couteau-sous-gorge-cameron))
>
> La BCE met le couteau sur la gorge de la Grèce. (Source : [Franceinfo](http://www.francetvinfo.fr/replay-radio/tout-info-tout-eco/la-bce-met-le-couteau-sur-la-gorge-de-la-grece_1771547.html))

Le *Dictionnaire des expressions et locutions figurées* (Les usuels du Robert, 1979) signale que bien que l'expression originale soit « avoir le couteau sur la gorge » dans l'usage moderne, « **sous** la gorge »  est plus fréquent que « **sur** la gorge », tendance confirmée par un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=couteau%20sur%20la%20gorge%2C%20couteau%20sous%20la%20gorge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccouteau%20sur%20la%20gorge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouteau%20sous%20la%20gorge%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Ou le classique "mettre une tronçonneuse rouillée à deux centimètres de ton visage". Non c'est faux je l'ai inventé.